# Can captures in Java generics be unified in type declarations?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Consider the following Java function:

```
public void foo(Class<? extends Exception> cl, List<? extends Exception> ls) throws Exception {
    ls.add(cl.newInstance());
}
```

This does not work, since the type captures of `cl` and `ls` are not unified and can, indeed, refer to different types. Had this function compiled, I could have called it as `foo(NullPointerException.class, new List<SecurityException>())`, which would have been illegal.

We can fix this, obviously, by unifying the type captures, like this:

```
public <T extends Exception> void foo(Class<T> cl, List<T> ls) throws Exception {
    ls.add(cl.newInstance());
}
```

Now this function works as expected. Thus, onto my question: Is there any way to unify type captures within a single type declaration?

For example, I often find myself wanting a map that maps classes to instances of themselves. The only way I can currently think of doing this is to have an accompanying function that does unchecked casts:

```
private Map<Class<? extends Foo>, ? extends Foo> map = ...;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T extends Foo> T getFoo(Class<T> cl) {
    return((T)map.get(cl));
}
```

But it would obviously be nicer to not have to suppress warnings and just have the compiler understand that the two type captures in the map type declaration should be the same, and then just make the map public. For example, if I could have a declaration akin to this:

```
<T extends Foo> Map<Class<T>, T> map = ...;
```

Obviously, that's not valid syntax, but my question boils down to: Is there any valid syntax that would let my do something to that effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Generics of a Higher Kind](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2579). Java does not have them and likely never will. I realize that this is a Java question, nonetheless I will point out that [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) has higher kinds. If you want to see what it means to have such power in a type system, you might want to play with it.

Answer (score 2):

Not without suppressing some warnings.

You really don't want to do this by making `Map` "special" in the type system -- what about `Function` types, or what have you?  Describing the sort of complex relationships like "this class corresponds only to instances of this class" is something that's extremely difficult even in highly advanced type systems -- I'm not even sure Agda can do it, and Agda has the strongest type system I know of.

Of course, you can wrap it in an internally unsafe, externally safe API, cf. Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html).  But you can't make that sort of guarantee at compile time.

Comment: I don't at all intend to make `Map` special in any way. Given that the type `Map<K, V>` has a function declared as `V get(K key)`, I think it should be possible to make the compiler understand that a `Map<Class<T>, T>` has a function `T get(Class<T> key)`, which would achieve the effect I want. The problem, in my case, is that the function effectively becomes `X get(Class<Y> key)`, and I simply want to unify `X` and `Y`.

Comment: That's still awfully narrow and specific.  What about guaranteeing the safety of `Map.put`?  What about `ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent`?  You're not going to find a way to generically determine whether or not a class has this property with `Class<T>` and `T`.  At the moment, the "correct solution" to problems like this is just to wrap it in an internally unsafe, externally safe API.

Comment: What are you saying would the problem with `Map.put`? Shouldn't a `Map<Class<T>, T>` properly gain a function `<T> T put(Class<T> key, T value)`?

Comment: You're suggesting that the compiler could be smart enough to identify all the different permutations of method signatures that you could have, _and_ identify the cases when you _don't_ want to unify `T` and `Class<T>`.  I'm saying that there are too many different variations for the compiler to be able to figure out when this is applicable, and when it isn't -- especially since the compiler can't be allowed false positives or false negatives.

Comment: I'm not saying that the compiler should be smart enough to figure it out for me, but rather wondering if there is any way for me to make it explicit for the compiler that `T` and `Class<T>` should be unified. I mean, it can obviously already handle it for the method declarations itself, where type variables can be created explicitly. It would simply be nice to be able to create similar type variables within a single type declaration. I don't think I'm asking for more than that, or am I?

Comment: What you're suggesting could be possible, but I think the issue you start running into now is that you're giving `Class<T>` special treatment, where it had very little before (only the `getClass()` method in `Object`).  Heck, some projects roll their own extensions to type-based reflection -- Guice's TypeLiteral, for instance, which reduces the effects of type erasure at runtime, due to a cool trick -- and what happens to those?  This would all be a lot of effort from Oracle for not very much benefit -- you can already simulate the behavior you desire.

Comment: All this said, I suppose that in theory you could do something with an annotation processor which might actually do the checking you want, for these specific cases.  I'm not aware of anyone who's actually done that, though.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
public static <T extends Exception> void foo(Class<T> cl, List<? super T> ls) throws Exception {
    ls.add(cl.newInstance());
}
```

? Also good points can be found in Effective Java ([Producer Extends Consumer Super](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=producer+extends+consumer+super&source=bl&ots=yYEnPhv3TZ&sig=JfZFk5gFGmt1pOlUvPyXLq5RUmA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cPEyT4XHC5H5sgaMk_ChDA&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=producer%20extends%20consumer%20super&f=false))

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to "unify" is by using a type variable, and a type variable always stands for the same type throughout the entire declaration that introduces it. There is no way to introduce a type variable that stands for a different type for every entry in the map, because you can't add a type variable to `Map.Entry`.

I described the impossibility of meaningfully constraining the map's entry type in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408256/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-wildcard-types-to-be-of-same-type/8408867#8408867).

Of course, if you don't have to implement the Map interface, but simply want to offer a `put` and `get` method, you can use a method scoped type variable to unify. But as soon as you want an `addAll()` method you go beyond the expressiveness of Java's type system.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I could come up with is extending an implementation of the Map interface, and declare it as such:

```
public class ClassMap<T extends Foo> extends HashMap<Class<T>, T>
```

Although it seems like you don't want to have to implement something else to do this.

Comment: Erm, that doesn't work? The value of the type parameter would have to be provided upon construction of the ClassMap, thereby locking it down to only ever contain a single entry.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, reason of your problem is the understanding of generics and using wild cards.

The first example presented by you word as should.

```
public void foo(Class<? extends Exception> cl, List<? extends Exception> ls) throws Exception;
```

is the same as having

```
public void foo(Class<Integer> c1, List<String> ls) throws Exception
```

What i wan to present is that in both cases the parameters do not have anything in common.

If we want to force that, two argument use the same generic parameter we need to declare it in section for generic arguments.

```
public <T extends Exception> void foo(Class<T> cl, List<T> ls) throws Exception
```

Ok, now we ensured that both arguments will have to use a type that extends `Exception` class

This solution has some limits, so we can improve by introducing, a wild card `? super T`, witch generally stand for T or superclass.

```
public <T extends Exception> void foo(Class<T> cl, List<? super T> ls) throws Exception
```

Back to your original question "Is there any valid syntax that would let my do something to that effect?"

To use same generic parameter in a field and method, the scope of him should be class.

```
public class Foo<T extends Exception> { 

   private Map<Class<T>,T> map;

   public void T getFoo(Class<T> clazz) {
     return map.get(clazz);
   }

}
```

But if you do not want the generic type in class definition there is no way to guaranty that generic type of method is the same as generic type of a field.

So the final solution for you case, is that if you create a encapsulated map, and proper use method to set and retrieve objects, then a suppress of warning is not bad thing. Because you ensured in other way the safety of type.