# Using Java Generics to make two types the same

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following:

```
public interface Sendable<T> { T details() }
public interface Receiver<T> { void receive(T details) }
```

I want to make a mapping from a Sendable of any type to a Receiver of the same type. They need to be the same type because at some point I want to call

```
receiver.receive(sendable.details());
```

and the compiler would otherwise reject it. I plan on sending many types. I could do something like :

```
public class Foo {
  Map<Sendable<Integer>, Receiver<Integer>> intmap;
  Map<Sendable<String>, Receiver<String>> stringmap;
  ... 
  //put a map for each type
}
```

but then I would have to update this class every time I wanted to send some new type. I want to do something like

```
public class Foo {
  Map<Sendable<?>, Receiver<?>> map;
}
```

since I would only have to write it once and be done with it forever, but this obviously doesn't work because a ? is not a ?. So how can I make a map from T to T for any T?

No casting, that defeats the point of static typing.

Comment: What the matter with `Receiver<T>#receive( Sendable<T> send )`?

Comment: I don't know, what does the # mean

Comment: It means that you call a method on an instance of `Receiver`, rather than the `Receiver` class, i.e. `receive` is a non-`static` method in Java.

Comment: I want to write                                                                 
```Foo#method(Sendable<?> sendable) { this.map.get(sendable).receive(sendable.details())                                             
}```

Comment: Sounds like [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) will get in your way at runtime. You probably want to use a map keyed by`Class` type and use it to fetch the respective sendable and receiver.

Comment: So Receiver<T>#receive( Sendable<T> send ) would just make it Foo#method(Sendable<?> sendable) { this.map.get(sendable).receive(sendable) }

Comment: @cleberz I tried a Map<Class<?>, Map<Sendable<T>, Receiver<T>> but it won't accept it because there's nowhere to declare T

Comment: Would something like this be what you're looking for? 
`Map<Class<?>,Map<Sendable<?>,Receiver<?>>> map;`

Comment: The above will hold a map tied to the type in question. 
you can use
`Map<Sendable<?>, Receiver<?>> pair = new HashMap<Sendable<?>, Receiver<?>>();
  pair.put(sendable, receiver);
  map.put(sendable.getClass(), pair);`
to put data. I'd recommend using `Map.Entry` as a pair, instead of an actual `Map`

Comment: When I try to call ```this.map.get(sendable.getClass()).get(sendable).receive(sendable.details())``` it gives me a type error because the type of sendable.details() is a ?

Comment: Apparently they decided this was impossible back in 2011, as casting would be required :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408256/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-wildcard-types-to-be-of-same-type